# Unable to insert data into specific table partition, it is showing identity error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2022

Unable to insert data into specific table partition it is showing identity error.

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 172
>
> An explicit value for the
> identity column in table 'dbo.orders' can only be specified when a
> column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

To solve this I set IDENTITY OFF before insert and ON after insert. But the SQL identity issue persists. I also tried vice-versa.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[orders] OFF;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[orders] SELECT OrderID,OrderDate,ProductID,CustomerName,TotalAmount FROM dbo.orders6 WHERE $PARTITION.[order_by_year_function](OrderDate) in (3);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[orders] ON;
```

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[orders] ON;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[orders] SELECT OrderID,OrderDate,ProductID,CustomerName,TotalAmount FROM dbo.orders6 WHERE $PARTITION.[order_by_year_function](OrderDate) in (3);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[orders] OFF;
```

Comment: You haven't resolved the **"when a column list is used"** part of the error message. You need `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[orders] ON;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[orders](OrderID,OrderDate,ProductID,CustomerName,TotalAmount) SELECT ...`

Comment: By the way which table is partitioned here? `[dbo].[orders]` or `dbo.orders6` or both?

Comment: orders table partitioned.

Comment: 1st I moved from table partition 3 of the order table into the staging table order6. Later I deleted it from partitioned table 3 of those data. Later I tried to insert those data into that partition 3 again to check whether it is properly fit those data or not.

Comment: I think you mean INSERT INTO [dbo].[orders](OrderID,OrderDate,ProductID,CustomerName,TotalAmount) SELECT OrderID,OrderDate,ProductID,CustomerName,TotalAmount FROM dbo.orders6 WHERE $PARTITION.[order_by_year_function](OrderDate) in (3);